# Calling a module function inside a class

Tags: python, class, module, networkx

I have a question about using a Python nodule inside a class function.

This is for a tkinter app that I am trying to create. When the user loads a text file is read in and used to create a NetworkX graph.  When I call the read in function in the class it is not able to access the NetworkX function.

The line of code causing the problem is below `self.graph` the graph object inside the class, and `add_node` is the NetworkX function I would like to call.

```
def __init__ (self, master = None, g = nx.graph, v = 'Some Number')
    #Call varibales
    self.graph = g
    self.value = v

def add_node():
    self.graph.add_node(self.value)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hm.. the way your code is currently written, you're assigning the class itself (`nx.graph`) to `g`.

That, is a bit wrong, you'll need to instantiate `nx.graph`, so `g` is an instance of it:

```
def __init__ (self, master = None, g = nx.graph(), v = 'Some Number')
```

This way, g will be an instance of `nx.graph` when you make instantiate your class.

Alternatively, you can instantiate it when you assigned it to `self.graph`:

```
def __init__ (self, master = None, g = nx.graph, v = 'Some Number')
    #Call varibales
    self.graph = g()
    self.value = v
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.  This worked.  I needed to instantiate not just make it the class itself.